# pg_upgradecluster to specific version? ( more than 2 version )

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-cluster

Theres a way to upgrade a cluster of postgreSQL to specific version?.

An example:

I have a 9.4.17 - 9.6.8 and 10.3

The 10.3 has cluster on
The 9.4.17 has cluster on

I need upgrade the 9.4.17 to 9.6.8, i'm wondering if i use:

pg_upgradecluster 9.4 main

The cluster will be upgraded to the latest version ( i guess 10.3 ). I need update the cluster to 9.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-v` flag of `pg_upgradecluster` allows you to specify the new version you want.

From https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/postgresql-common/pg_upgradecluster.1.en.html :

```
-v newversion
Set the version to upgrade to (default: latest available).
```

So `pg_upgradecluster -v 9.6.8 9.4 main` for you.

It is of course always recommended to have backups before starting anything.